# How does 'double' to 'unsigned char' casting work?

Tags: c++, windows, computer-science

I want to be able to cast double into an 'unsigned char' and I don't seem to get why the 'unsigned char' result came in character '>' even when casting is done (inside the function). Can anyone explain to me where the issue lies and how to fix it? That would be a great help.

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 unsigned char f_wd(double force1);

 int main() {
 double x = 512;

  int dog = f_wd(x);
  cout << dog << endl;            // this outputs 62 

  unsigned char cat = f_wd(x);
  cout << cat << endl;             // but this outputs '>'

}


 unsigned char f_wd(double force1){
 double animal = (124.0/1024)*force1;
unsigned char animal2 = (unsigned char)animal;
 return animal2;

 }
```

Comment: `cout << static_cast<unsigned int>(cat) << endl;`

Comment: `cout << +cat << endl;` (this does the same thing as above, but a little less clearly. Do what WhozCraig suggests)

Comment: @WhozCraig Can it instead not be assigned into an 'unsigned char' variable?  for example, (unsigned char zebra = (unsigned char)dog

Comment: @AnkitZyada *"Can it instead not be assigned into an 'unsigned char' variable?"* - I don't understand the question. You seem to effectively be asking, "Can I *not* do what I'm doing?" - Well... *yeah*, of course. I have no earthly idea what moved you to do this with an unsigned char in the first place. I (perhaps egregiously) assumed you had your reasons, and was simply pointing to the fact that `std::ostream` has defined behavior  for handling unsigned char (and char) types, to emit them as the characters their values dictate on the active code page. Casting to unsigned int skips that logic.

Comment: @AnkitZyada `cout << (dog == cat) << endl;` will output `1`  so you are just printing the same value in two different formats - integer vs. character.

Comment: @JohnFilleau: Why is it less clear? This is an idiomatic use of the unary `+` operator - widens to an `int`, leaves wider types alone. In other words I prefer your way.

Comment: @Bathsheba I find the unary `+` to be hard to visually parse.